# Is pre-whitening needed for regression on time series data

Tags: regression, time-series, whitening

I am trying to build a regression model for two time series x (independent) and y (dependent) to get y=f(x).

I read from other posts saying you have to pre-whitening your time series for both x and y and then make regression on the stationary data (e.g.[Forecast time series data with external variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212912/forecast-time-series-data-with-external-variables)). But there are also people who said it is not necessary. I am very confused because if the trend in y can be explained by the trending in x, why do we still need to do that pre-whitening? And what is exactly the right procedure to do it?

I would really appreciate it if you could give me some guidance on this.